# How to implement For each

Tags: jquery

For each of the below code:

```
$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text();
```

I need to perform the below lines of code:

```
var sub_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td a").text();
var next_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text().substring(14, 30);

//full_text.text(full_text.text().replace(sub_text, next_text));
```

How to achieve this using for each in jquery?

Comment: You should look up the [jQuery each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function:

```
var items = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td")
$.each(items, function(i, val){
   var item = $(val);
   var sub_text = item.find('a').text();
   var next_text = item.text();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) > tbody:nth-child(even) > tr > td').each(function () {
        var sub_text = $(this).find('a').text();
        var next_text = $(this).text().substring(14, 30);

    });
```

UPDATE:-

```
$('.landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) > tbody:nth-child(even) > tr > td').each(function () {          
            var next_text = $(this).text().substring(14, 30);
            $(this).find('a').text("<a>" + next_text + "</a>");
        });
```

UPDATE 2:-

to fetch SubCategory wrap it into a span like below in ur html:-

```
<span class="sub-cat">SubCategory </span>
```

and u can fetch it like:-

```
item.find('a').find('.sub-cat').text();
```

Comment: expandSubcategory : Mutual Funds (4),Subcategory : SMAs (6),Subcategory : UCITS (1)  These are the 3 lines of code present  in my UI.I want to replace "Subcategory" text present in each line with the text which comes after ":" respectively.How to achieve using below lines which are written by me.var full_text=$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").;
  var sub_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td a").text();
  var next_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text().substring(14, 30);

Comment: The code which you given is fetching the text before and after the ":"(Colon).This is exactly fine.At the same time i want to replace the sub_text with next_text.Kindly help me on the same

Comment: i dont understand that.. can u post your html?

Comment: This is a share point environment.Anyways i ll post the same :<td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb"><a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('0-1_', 'img_0-1_',event, false);return false;"><span class="ms-commentcollapse-iconouter"><img class="ms-commentcollapse-icon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="expand" id="img_0-1_"></span>Subcategory</a> : Mutual Funds <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(4)</span></td>

Comment: see i have update my ans what i understood from ur query @bhavyagh

Comment: yes its replacing the text but the anchor functionality is been removed after the replacement.How to restore it

Comment: <span class="ms-commentexpand-iconouter"><img class="ms-commentexpand-icon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="expand" id="img_8-1_"></span>Subcategory.......How to access the subcategory alone using the below code...item.find('a').html();

Comment: item.find('a').html();
 will fetch me the above lines of code.How can i fetch only subcategory which is outside the span tag

Comment: but that "subcategory" is outside the span tag.

Comment: take another span tag as mentioned in update @bhavyagh